# Where i can find windows 64 bit box for vagrant

Tags: docker, vagrant

I searched lot for vagrant windows 64 bit box.Can anybody help me?
I already searched on vagrant site but it has only 32 bit windows box and i need 64 bit box.

Answer (score 0):

The [Atlas site](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search?utm_source=vagrantcloud.com&vagrantcloud=1) is very useful to find all kind of boxes. Here, this one seems to fit your purpose :

https://vagrantcloud.com/tnitti/boxes/windows-8.1-amd64